# v-if statement not having an effect in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

Code which works in the [Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpFjkEOgjAQRa8ydIMulLA1hegJ3LnqBskAjdA27RQXhHu4M/GEHsEiKLv5mfdf/sBOxux7j+zAuCutNAQOyZtcKNkZbQkGsFjBCJXVHcQBjYUSqtTKERR3dLpDyCZmQ9bjViiezKKgCIGwM21BGBIAv3oireBYtrK8ZYKtgmg5BctJ13WLPJnhr0YQb1Lod7JaS4G8eATpfjMinjTphC8wtg7zcwNKw/v5eC1fnvwnsfEDwaha7w==) is not functioning in my Vue app. Specifically, the `v-if` statement in my `App.vue` is never rendered (the `v-else` always is) regardless of how many times the `button` is pressed:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const awesome = ref(true)
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="awesome = !awesome">toggle</button>

  <h1 v-if="awesome">Vue is awesome!</h1>
  <h1 v-else>Oh no </h1>
</template>
```

#### Additional Information:

- I am using Vue CLI.
- Code instructions such as `v-for` work perfectly.

Comment: your code works fine over on [https://play.vuejs.org](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpFjkEOgjAQRa8ydIMulLA1hegJ3LnqBskAjdA27RQXhHu4M/GEHsEKKLuZzPtv/sBOxux7j+zAuCutNAQOyZtcKNkZbQkGsFjBCJXVHcQBjYUSqtTKERR3dLpDyL7MhqzHrVA8mUVBERbCzrQFYdgA+NUTaQXHspXlLRNsFUTLKFhOuq5b5MkMT5oQbVLod7JaQ4G8eATpfjUinjTp/GeCsXWYnxtQGt7Px2u58uRfiY0feKBZzw==)

Comment: check your browser *developer* tools console for errors/messages

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Don't make us guess at the rest of your code.

Comment: @Unmitigated I provided the example; that is _all_ my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code executed once found no problem, you can try to restart the following file try? Or check to see if there are any other error messages